# Linq query to get max values among lines in .csv file

Tags: c#, linq

I have `.csv` file. First value in each line is `DateTime`. How can I get its maximum (latest) value using Linq? Please continue or change (if it don't need to use let keyword) my query:

```
 var maxDT = from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                  let dt = DateTime.Parse(line.Split(',')[0])
               .
               .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single maximum value

```
var dateTime = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\file.svc")
.Select(l => DateTime.Parse(l.Split(',')[0]))
.Max();

// query expression
var date = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\file.csv")
           let date = DateTime.Parse(line.Split(',').First())
           orderby date descending
           select date).First()
```

If you need say, the top 5 maximum

```
 var dates = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\file.svc")
 .Select(l => DateTime.Parse(l.Split(',')[0]))
 .OrderByDescending(d => d)
 .Take(count: 5);
```

Comment: `ReadAllLines` closes the File for you. `ReadLines` does not.

Answer (score 0):

About like this:

```
var maxDT = File.ReadLines (file)
    .Select (line => DateTime.Parse (line.Split (',') [0]))
    .Max ();
```